# How to implement iterator traversal for custom class in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator

Suppose I have a class that is just a wrapper over some standard container (for example, a `vector`, but could be any other container):

```
class Wrapper {
    public:
        Wrapper() = default;
        std::vector<int> vec;
};
```

I want to make it so that iterating over an instance of my class is the same as iterating over the underlying container. For example, I would like to write something like:

```
Wrapper w;
// ... input some data into vec

std::for_each(w.begin(), w.end(), [](const auto& elem) {
   std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}
```

How do I go about doing this?
What is the minimum required implementation for something like this? What is needed for a full implementation such that the `Wrapper` class can be used with most/all standard algorithms?

I am looking for a C++17 approach, without relying on boost or other non-standard libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution is to just return the container's own iterators, eg:

```
class Wrapper {
    public:
        Wrapper() = default;
        std::vector<int> vec;

        auto begin() { return vec.begin(); }
        auto end() { return vec.end(); }
};
```

---

On a side note: your `for_each()` can be simplified using a [range-for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead:

```
for(const auto& elem : w) {
   std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: How is this enough? How do standard algorithms know how to advance the iterators if I have not implemented such a method? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: This code is using the iterators that `std::vector` has *already implemented* for itself. So, the algorithms will effectively be iterating the contents of the `vector` directly, even though the iterators were retrieved from your class. IOW, `std::for_each(w.begin(), w.end(), ...)` is the same as `std::for_each(w.vec.begin(), w.vec.end(), ...)` It doesn't get more efficient than that. That is the beauty of using iterators - the algorithms don't care *where* they come from. The algorithms are able to advance the iterators because the iterators themselves have `operator++`  implemented on them.